# Is my code out on the internet for good after an accidental npm publish?

Tags: npm, npm-publish

My computer took a dump while I was working on some code, so I restarted it. I jumped back into the code and hit the up arrow and the enter key in my terminal. For whatever reason, the last command was `npm publish` not `npm start`. I hit `CTRL-C` and it stopped, but then I got an email that the publish was successful. I quickly `npm unpublish`ed. Overall time from publish to unpublished was probably about 1 minute.

I know there are bots that download and store NPM modules. What are the chances one grabbed that accidentally published module? Is my code out there for good now?

The code is very sensitive and I'm worried!